# mongodb - perform subquery

Tags: c++, mongodb

a document:

```
   { "_id":1, "id":1, "list" : [ { "lv" : 1 , "id":1}, {"lv" : 2 , "id":2} ] }
```

I want do find({"_id":1},{"id":1, "list.lv":1}) but limit {"list.lv":1} with an additional condition: "list.id = id". That means I only want to retrieve "id" and the "list.lv" part of the first element in list because its "list.id" == "id" == 1

Normally the condition value provided in code, but in this example, the value is in the document. SQL do this by subquery or join table. Does mongodb support this in a single query? And how to write it in c++ driver?

**According to answer, add c++ code:**

```
mongo::BSONObj res;
std::vector<mongo::BSONObj> pipeline;
pipeline.push_back(BSON("$match"<<BSON("_id"<<1)));
pipeline.push_back(BSON("$unwind"<<"$list"));
mongo::BSONArrayBuilder ab;
ab<<"$id"<<"$list.id";
pipeline.push_back(BSON("$project"<<BSON("id"<<1<<"list.lv"<<1<<"equalsFlag"<<BSON("$subtract"<<ab.arr()))));
pipeline.push_back(BSON("$match"<<BSON("equalsFlag"<<0)));
pipeline.push_back(BSON("$project"<<BSON("id"<<1<<"list.lv"<<1)));
conn->runCommand("db_name", BSON( "aggregate" << "collection_name" << "pipeline" << pipeline ), res);
std::cout<<res["result"].Array()[0].Obj().getObjectField("list").getIntField("lv");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you question try this native [aggregate framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) query to accomplish what you need:

```
db.collectionName.aggregate(
{"$match" : {"_id" : 1 }}, 
{"$unwind" : "$list"}, 
{"$project" : {"id":1, "list.lv" : 1, "equalsFlag" : {"$subtract" : ["$id", "$list.id"]}}}, 
{"$match" : {"equalsFlag" : 0}}, 
{"$project" : {"id": 1, "list.lv" : 1}})
```

Let me explain it in more detail. It's important to filter out as much documents as we can at first. We can do it with the first [$match](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match). Note that if we do {"_id" : 1 } filter at the end of the pipeline mongo will not be able to use index for it. [$unwind](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) will turn each list array element into a seperate document. Then we need to compare two fields. I'm not aware of any easy way to do it except for [$where](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) but we cant use it with aggregate framework. Fortunately both *id* and *list.id* are numeric so we can *$subtract* one from another to see if they are equal, "equalsFlag" : {"$subtract" : ["$id", "$list.id"]} . If they are, *equalsFlag* will be 0. So we just add a new *$match* to get documents where *id=list.id* and finally to omit equalsFlag field from results we have one more $project.

I'm not a C++ guy but I'm sure C++ driver supports aggregate framework as most of other drivers. So just google some examples to convert this native query into a C++ one. This should be fairly easy at least it's true for C#.

**EDIT:** C++ code from jean to complete the answer

```
mongo::BSONObj res;
std::vector<mongo::BSONObj> pipeline;
pipeline.push_back(BSON("$match"<<BSON("_id"<<1)));
pipeline.push_back(BSON("$unwind"<<"$list"));
mongo::BSONArrayBuilder ab;
ab<<"$id"<<"$list.id";
pipeline.push_back(BSON("$project"<<BSON("id"<<1<<"list.lv"<<1<<"equalsFlag"<<BSON("$subtract"<<ab.arr()))));
pipeline.push_back(BSON("$match"<<BSON("equalsFlag"<<0)));
pipeline.push_back(BSON("$project"<<BSON("id"<<1<<"list.lv"<<1)));
conn->runCommand("db_name", BSON( "aggregate" << "collection_name" << "pipeline" << pipeline ), res);
std::cout<<res["result"].Array()[0].Obj().getObjectField("list").getIntField("lv");
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I works. And I also add C++ driver code in my question.